# Why doesn't ${1:r} strip file extension in my zsh script?

Tags: zsh

I'm writing a zsh script that automates some video encoding. The file to be converted will be the first parameter to the script, which contains this line:

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -ac 0 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 500k -crf 20 ${1:r}.mp4
```

I expected `${1:r}.mp4` to create a file with the same name as my .mov input, but with the .mp4 file extension replacing .mov. But instead I get input.mov.mp4. Why isn't the :r modifier stripping the file extension?

Comment: Okay, stupid question first: it really is a zsh script, you run it with `zsh` and there is no `#!/bin/bash` or similar , right? Now, with that gotten out of the way: it is a bit hard to guess what is going wrong. Is this the whole script? Do you have any settings in `~/.zshenv` or `/etc/zshenv` (or maybe `/etc/zsh/zshenv`)? If you put `setopt` inside the script, does it produce any output, if yes, what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I experienced something similar and it seems like zsh doesn't accept :r on the positional arguments. Instead you could do something like this:

```
file=${1}
ffmpeg -i $1 -ac 0 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 500k -crf 20 ${file:r}.mp4
```